# While using  iphone PhotoLibrary, Restrict user to select any video file more than duration of 60secs?

Tags: iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller, duration

Is there any method available to **check video file duration** as soon as user select Video from iPhone photo library ? And restrict user to select if that video file is more than 60secs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0f;` // limits video length to 60 seconds.

where imagePickerController is object of UIImagePickerController.

Using videoMaximumDuration method you can restrict length of video from both ways. Like if you are recording video an alert will popup saying you cannot record video more than 60 sec and if you are selecting any video file from your library, first it will check the length of your video if length is more than 60 sec. Again alert will popup saying video is larger than 60 sec but there will be two options i.e. use or cancel.  If you select use then it will crop the length of video upto 60sec from the beginning.

Comment: This does _not_ limit the length of the video that can be selected. It limits the length of the video that can be _recorded_.

Comment: @harkonian: I have tested this function. So basically what its doing if you are recording video then it will not take any video more than 60 sec already tested. And if you take any large length video from iphone library then a alert pop-up saying this video is larger than 60sec. If you again select use instead of cancel then it will crop length of video to 60sec. This part is also tested.

Comment: Are you certain the alert pop-up for _picking_ a video longer than 60 seconds is not your custom code somewhere or maybe you are listening to a particular UIImagePickerController notification? I put together a new test harness and set `videoQuality` to high, and `videoMaximumDuration` to 10 seconds. I pick a video that is 15 minutes long and it picks it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

videoMaximumDuration method alert you as soon as 60 sec reached

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter assets using the `UIImagePicker`. However, using the new Asset Library Frameworks, you can fairly easily create your own video picker that filters videos based on your criteria.

For a good head start on doing this, here is a github repository that has recreated the UIImagePicker functionality using the Asset Library Frameworks: https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController . You'll also want to look at the documentation for the `ALAssetsFilter` for setting up filter criteria.

Here is a video demoing the control: http://vimeo.com/15666311

And here is his blog where he talks a bit about the control: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

```
self.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"Duration: %f",(float) self.player.duration]
```

And ultimately output:

```
self.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Running Time: %d min",(int) ceil(self.player.duration/60)];
```

Answer (score -1):

From the [IPhone SDK Application Development: Building Applications for the AppStore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596154054)

> You can also read the duration of the sample (in seconds) through the `duration` property. This, too, is represented as an `NSTimeInterval`, which is typed to a double floating-point:
>
> ```
> NSTimeInterval duration = player.duration
> ```

Comment: Care to explain why you originally posted this as an image? Then see: [Using only an image as an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116050/using-only-an-image-as-an-answer) Thanks! (Thanks, @hammar, too!)