# UIImagePickerController crash when trying to select panoramic image from phone library

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to select an image from device library using the UIImagePickerController all things works well unless i pick a very huge image ( a panoramic image) the app crash without giving any trace. I think it is a memory issue ( i noticed that the memory usage is increasing to 600m). So my question is can i specify an image size as a filter ? or should i create my custom image picker ? also i tested the same image using facebook and twitter image picker : twitter fail ...

my code launch the image picker is :

```
var picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
presentViewController(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and capturing the selected image :

```
extension MYViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    func imagePickerController(
    picker: UIImagePickerController,
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        print("user did select an image")
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        //do code when cancel
        print("cancel ...")
        userDidCancelImageChoosing = true
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**edit**: I checked the question of video duration but is not what I need we don't have the same problem, Here I talk about selecting image from the image picker you can try in the twitter app and attach a panoramic HQ image with huge size. The question suggested talk about limiting record video duration.

Comment: I tried with the same code to fetch the pano image. All it happens is its taking just a couple of seconds to render the image from the photo library screen after you select, and then the screen dismisses.
I don't see the crash. I might not be helping your question, but sharing something that i did.

Comment: My problem is not with the code. The app crash when i select a huge image size

Comment: This may sadly be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11637993/218152

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While using  iphone PhotoLibrary, Restrict user to select any video file more than duration of 60secs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799962/while-using-iphone-photolibrary-restrict-user-to-select-any-video-file-more-th)

Answer (score 0):

The App crashes due to large size of Image.you can resize the image using the following function.This function will return an image. If you want data then uncomment the two lines and return Data instead of image.

```
func compressImage(image:UIImage) -> UIImage {
    // Reducing file size to a 10th

    var actualHeight : CGFloat = image.size.height
    var actualWidth : CGFloat = image.size.width
    let maxHeight : CGFloat = 1136.0
    let maxWidth : CGFloat = 640.0
    var imgRatio : CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
    let maxRatio : CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth){
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio){
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
        else{
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
            compressionQuality = 1;
        }
    }


    let rect = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: actualWidth, height: actualHeight)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);


    image.draw(in: rect)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img ?? UIImage.init(named: "imgPlaceHolder")!, compressionQuality);
    //
    //        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //
    return img ?? image
}
```

Code to use this function

```
        picker.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
            let img = self.compressImage(image: chosenImage)
            let cropViewController = TOCropViewController(image: img)
            cropViewController.delegate = self
            self.present(cropViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

        })
```